# Use function which is also a keyword

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I am currently writing a test for a `RestController` with a `WebMvcTest`. However, unlike Java, `is` is a keyword in `Kotlin`. Is there a quick way to fix this issue? See the below snippet.

```
mockMvc.perform(post("/networks")
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(StorageNetworkDTO(name = "Test Network"))))
    .andExpect(status().isCreated)
    .andExpect(jsonPath("\$.name", Matchers.is("Test Network")))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Escaping for Java identifiers that are keywords in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#escaping-for-java-identifiers-that-are-keywords-in-kotlin):

> you can still call the method escaping it with the backtick (`) character

```
foo.`is`(bar)
```